# RewriteRule not working. 403 Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to block access to all `.php` files in all my directories, but I need to keep one single file available so it can process user requests, but my RewriteRule is not working. How to make it to work?

Here is my .htaccess :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files ~ "\.(txt|xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|pdf)$">
  Allow from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "start\.php$">
  Allow from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /start.php [QSA]
```

Now if I want to access for example `http://localhost/test` it shows an 403 Error : `You don't have permission to access /test on this server.`

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this is moving all `.php` files outside your document root and only keep `start.php` inside. This effectively prevents access to any `.php` file, except the one you want allow to.

---

The other solution is configuration based, which is more expensive, because Apache must check the rules for each file requested.

Access to `http://localhost/test` is denied, because you have

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

and the `Files` sections do not apply here. See the [`Order Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order) for details, especially the table, where you have

```
Match               Allow,Deny result   Deny,Allow result
---------------------------------------------------------
Match Deny only     Request denied      Request denied
```

---

If you want the `Deny from all` for the given files only, you must move it inside a [`FilesMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#filesmatch) section

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "start\.php$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

You can use a [`Files`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#files) section too, of course, but notice the sidenote

> <FilesMatch> is preferred, however.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, I haven't tested it. I have removed all the `deny/allow` rules.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f // the request is a file
RewriteCond $1 ^.+\.php$ // the requested file has php extension
RewriteCond $1 !^start\.php // and is not that start.php file (the one you will allow)
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L] // forbid request
```

Just remove the `//` comments. They are not htaccess valid comments.